# How to call a delegate method from a class method in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I want to call a delegate method from a class method.

My demo code

**ClassA.h**

```
@interface ClassA: NSObject<MyProtocol>

+ (void)demoMethod;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyProtocol> delegate;
```

**ClassA.m**

```
+ (void)demoMethod {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(refreshViewController)]) {
                [self.delegate refreshViewController];
       }
  }
```

The error in above code is:

- No member named 'delegate' in 'struct objc_class'
- Member reference type 'struct objc_class *' is a pointer; did you
  mean to use '->'?

Please help me out to call a delegate method from a class method

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access instance properties from a static (class) function.

In your case, in your demo method, `self` does not refer to an *instance* of `ClassA`, but to `ClassA` itself.

There is no general solution to this behaviour; they all are kind-of work-arounds, depending on your needs:

- Keep a static reference to *the instance* (somehow a singleton approach)
- Don't make `demoMethod` a static function
- Keep the current / latest delegate in a static property and use this

Answer (score 0):

If you want access it from class then `delegate` should be class variable:

```
@interface ClassA: NSObject<MyProtocol>

+ (void)demoMethod;
@property (nonatomic, weak, class) id<MyProtocol> delegate;
```